# Why isn't git auto-merging files I haven't touched?

Tags: git, merge, diff

I'm trying to wrap my head around git, and one thing that's happening is that after I commit all my changes to my feature branch, and then try to merge between the feature branch and master, git shows 300 merge conflicts in files that I haven't touched. Shouldn't git be smart enough to just auto-merge the files I haven't touched? Why am I on an endless manual merge of files that I haven't even modified? It looks like it will take hours to resolve all these conflicts, and I might even risk copying over the latest changes in the master branch.

basically I just did:

```
feature-branch> git add --all
feature-branch> git commit -m "comment"
feature-branch> git push origin feature
feature-branch> git checkout master
master-branch> git pull origin master
master-branch> git merge feature
```

Is this just the way it is, or am I missing a step or two?

Comment: git won't attempt to merge files that have not been touched. it owuld be interesting though, what the actual merge-conflicts are that you are seeing. i suspect that you changed the line-endings ("CRLF vs LF") during checkout and with `git add --all` you committed them, thus touching *all* the files, rather than none.

Comment: I doubt that's the case because we're all working on the same type of machine (mac) and using the same repo (bitbucket). And all of the git adds I've done have never shown files I haven't touched.

Comment: Which types of files are in conflict ? Can you give an example of the conflict you have ?

Comment: I am willing to bet money it's because of EOL-format changes in the files.... if I had a dime for every single time I've said this on this site... I would be just as broke as I have ever been.

Comment: EOL-format? Well we're working on a Vue app and we use Typescript. All of the files that that git says needs merging that we didn't touch are .ts file (i.e. TypeScript). How can I test if this is an EOL issue? I generated the files from a mac, uploaded to bitbucket, then clone to other macs. It's not like we're spanning the project across different file systems.

Comment: Is this normal: user1 creates a new repo. User2 clones the repo and makes a new feature branch. User 1 changes file1 and pushes it to master. User2 changes file2 and pushes it to the feature branch. User2 switches to master branch, does a pull, then does a git merge <feature branch>. User2 is asked to merge file1. Is that correct? It seems that a merge can be automatic there because user2 didn't even touch file1. So if there's a significant amount of files that have changed in master, user2 is stuck merging all the files that have changed since her last pull even if she never touched them